# How to find x in this case $\frac{x}{2}-1=e^x$?

Tags: numerical-methods

$$\frac{x}{2}-1=e^x$$

Let say we can write above function as: 
$$\frac{x}{2(e^x-1)}=1$$

In Wolframalpha I get a solution $x\approx -1.59362$.

How can I find x?

Comment: It should be $\frac{x}{2(e^x+1)}$

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout That makes sense.

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout When I write this function $\frac{x}{2(e^x-1)}=1$ in WA, I have a solution.

Comment: @Melina You're making a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @Melina, sure you have a solution of *that*, but you forgot to change the sign when you wrote $x/2 - 1 = e^x \implies x/2 = e^x - 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no solution in terms of elementary functions. Furthemore, there is no real solutuon, as shown in the answer by @cansomeonehelpmeout. However, you can use the [Lambert W-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) to get complex solutions:

$${x \over 2} - 1 = e^x$$
$$x-2 = 2e^x = 2e^{x-2}e^2$$
$$(x-2)e^{2-x}=2e^2$$
$$(2-x)e^{2-x}=-2e^2$$
$$2-x=W(-2e^2)$$
$$x=2-W(-2e^2)$$

Actually, $W$ is multi-valued. Taking the principal branch, we get $W_0(-2e^2) \approx 1.6718+2.2169i$, leading to $x\approx 0.3281-2.2169i$.

Comment: And what is that numerically? Note the numerical-methods tag.

Comment: @Ennar Gee, I missed that. Explains the downvotes.

Answer (score 5):

There is no real solution since

$$e^x\geq 1+x$$

For $x> -4$ we have $e^x\geq 1+x>\frac{x}{2}-1$, so $e^x-\left (\frac{x}{2}-1\right)>0$. This means that they don't intersect for $x\in \left <-4,\infty\right >$.

When $x\leq -4$ we have $e^x>0$ and so $e^x-\left (\frac{x}{2}-1\right )>0$ for $x\in \left <-\infty,-4\right]$. Therefore they don't intersect, and no real solution exists.

Comment: look at my edit.

Comment: @Melina it should be $2(e^x+1)$

Comment: I don't see how this inequality proves that no real solution exist. The only thing we can get is ${x\over 2}-1=e^x \Rightarrow {x\over 2}-1 \geq x+1 \Rightarrow x \leq -1$.

Comment: @lisyarus Because both of the functions are strictly increasing, i.e. they will never cross each other

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout I still don't see it. Could you elaborate in greater detail? How do you relate ${x\over 2}-1$ and $1+x$?

Comment: The vertical distance between two points, one on $e^x$ and one on $\frac{x}{2}-1$ is $D=e^x-\frac{x}{2}+1$. We are done if $D=0$. Now since $e^x\geq x+1>\frac{x}{2}-1$ we must have $D>0$, so they never cross. (I've edited my answer to hopefully make it more clear)

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout $x+1>{x\over 2}-1$ is not true for $x\leq -4$.

Comment: @lisyarus You're right, but $e^x>\frac{x}{2}-1$ is true since $e^x>0$ when $x\leq -4$

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout Ok, got it now, thank you. I feel that this separation into cases should be included in the answer.

Comment: @lisyarus Fixed! Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

$$ \frac{x}{2} - 1 = e^x $$
$$ \frac{x}{2} - 2 = e^x - 1  $$
$$ \frac{x-4}{2} = e^x -1 $$
$$ \frac{x-4}{2(e^x -1)} = 1 $$

> Let say we can write above function as:

You can't do that. Because then $x-4 = x \implies -4 = 0$, which is nonsense.

---

EDIT:

Assuming you meant:

$$ \frac{x}{2(e^x +1)} = 1 $$

Then you can just plot the function $f(x) = \frac{x}{2(e^x+1)}$ and solve $f(x) = 1$

EDIT 2:

I'm sure you're making a mistake:

[image]